# Using the "find -name" command on OS X

Tags: macos, terminal

In the command `find` theres a switch called name but it doesn't exist in OS X, whats the equivalent switch for OS X?

Comment: It's the same. Use "find . -name ..." -- you need to use directory where to search before other expressions like -name.

Comment: You should have provided this as an answer Peter

Comment: What may be confusing is that the default `find` on macOS is not the GNU version of find. The macOS version is [this](https://ss64.com/osx/find.html), the version that you see a lot of examples for is [the GNU version](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually you can use the find command as in unix e.g.: find . -name "*.log"

At least on all of my mac systems works this.

see 'man find':

```
-name pattern
         True if the last component of the pathname being examined matches
         pattern.  Special shell pattern matching characters (``['',
         ``]'', ``*'', and ``?'') may be used as part of pattern.  These
         characters may be matched explicitly by escaping them with a
         backslash (``\'').
```

Comment: My mistake kept thinking it was like a switch not an option so was putting my directory after it causing it to error.